# Receive 'SignatureDoesNotMatch' response when S3.getObject().promise()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

First of all, I solved issue but I want to know exactly why this happened.

I'm using `aws-sdk` for javascript v2 like

```js
await s3
    .getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: key }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(`Can't get object from "${bucketName}/${key}".`);
      }
    })
    .promise()
    .then((data) => {
      // decode data.Body
    })
```

This code caused twice requests. (Sorry, I couldn't show you in detail.)

```
/GET /{some-url} 
/GET /{some-url}
```

The difference between two requests is request header `x-amz-user-agent`.

One is `aws-sdk-js/2.1248.0 callback`.

The other one is `aws-sdk-js/2.1248.0 callback promise`.

And one which signature matches is `aws-sdk-js/2.1248.0 callback`.

The error response of other one is below.

```xml
<Error>
 <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
 <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.Check your key and signing method.</Message>
 <AWSAccessKeyId>{ACCESSKEYIDEXAMPLE}</AWSAccessKeyId>
 <StringToSign>
  AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
  20221123T001426Z
  20221123/{region-example}/s3/aws4_request
  29e50dd42fb05defb63ff9cd6d0ed6fd72d8078ac161d9a54fa704dbbeb88398
 </StringToSign>
 <SignatureProvided>4b302dcb0858f9c3d1289c9b957d86cd965f0b9909dbe88e08b68a4476f67e9c</SignatureProvided>
 <StringToSignBytes>...</StringToSignBytes>
 <CanonicalRequest>
  GET
  /{url-example}

  host:{s3-name-example}.s3.{region-example}.amazonaws.com
  x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
  x-amz-date:20221123T001426Z
  x-amz-security-token:{token-example}
  x-amz-user-agent:aws-sdk-js/2.1248.0 callback promise

  host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-user-agent
  UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
 </CanonicalRequest>
 <CanonicalRequestBytes>...</CanonicalRequestBytes>
 <RequestId>CKKWA23FWH266YRG</RequestId>
 <HostId>JQtVWn6BC2qLF4/LJlzYUzzo6Rlus2yvy6FdOvA9lEr4QkBmzSRzXPcFEYAkXSRRuEFvjEnAR3YUR5qTIsqADw==</HostId>
</Error>
```

I'm guessing that if a client sends several requests to AWS in too short interval, it sends only a single response.

Is it right? Or is there another reason?

Comment: I recommend upgrading to AWS SDK for JavaScript V3. Its better practice to use latest SDK version -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_GetObject_section.html

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, but I have to use V2.